# How to contact Canonical to sponsor an Event

Tags: community, canonical

The question should really start with "Is this possible to do", but assuming one can ask Canonical for permission to sponsor an event, I was wondering if they could help with gear. For example several T-Shirts with an Ubuntu Logo.

In my case it is the [FLISoL event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLISOL) (Latin American Free Software Install Fest) which occurs in several Latin American countries on the same day (April 27th.. 2 days after 13.04 is released) and it's objective is to teach new users the advantages of Open Source, how to install it and use it. Since I am the coordinator [this time around](http://flisol.org.ve/donde/maracaibo/) I wanted to know, who/where/how to contact if this is possible so we can get support related to Ubuntu.

Right now the team is composed of 6 people including me and the idea is to offer the shirts as a prize for users that answer some Ubuntu related questions and also to appear with the shirts when doing the Google Hangouts as part of the talks we will be doing during the Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend contacting them via their main phone numbers depending on your area these can be found here: http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/contact/our-offices

That's a good place to start, you could also contact their sales team here: http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/contact

The first one is faster but more broad, but I think the sales team would be your best bet.